# Share NodeJS Apps like Django

Tags: django, node.js

I come from a Django background, where to add functionality to the site you make an app. You can share that app between other Django projects.

In the Node world I haven't really seen anything like this. However, I want to write code that is reusable and useful to the community. So I'm wondering:

1. Do Node programmers share apps?
2. How would I structure an app so that it would be easy for someone to add to their site?

Comment: I also find the nodejs world lacking the ability to share code at "app" level. I rolled a small "framework" on my own. https://www.npmjs.org/package/dingo 

Currently, it allows me to define urls, views, tests, and templates in the same "app".

It doesn't support sharing at this point, unless you use unix `ln`. But, at least the parts of an app can be group together for future sharing, when sharing is finally implemented.

Comment: Whoever answer this question should have experienced or familiarity on how Django reusable apps work. The answer below is more from the Node JS perspective instead of Django perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js developers share functional packages of code called modules through the [*npm*](https://npmjs.org/) registry. The modules are used the same way as the [modules](http://nodejs.org/api/) shown in the documentation, and are typically utilized with `require()`. However, do take note that Django is a web framework, and Node is a programming language. Node is to Python as something like [Express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express) would be to Django.

There isn't any specific way to structure a Node module. You just need to make sure that the [`package.json`](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html) file is configured correctly so that the module can download any dependencies, set any binaries, and do general setup correctly.

Comment: So what I really need to do is find a specific framework and package for that?

Comment: What do you mean by "that"?

Comment: Let me try again: So what I really need to do is find a specific framework (like express) and package my app as that framework suggests?

Comment: If you're creating a web application, then yes.